# how to correctly use jquery with buttons rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

i have 2 radio buttons, when i click on text_field rails choose first radio button, then when i click to the second radio button rails choose button, the problems begins when i click again to the text_field rails doesnt choose needed button

```
<%= f.label "I will paid" %>
        <%= f.text_field :price %>  
        <%= f.radio_button :price, true %>
        <%= f.radio_button :price, false %>
        <%= f.label "let itself will offer price" %>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#post_price_false').click(function(){
            $('#post_price').val(''); 
          });
          $('#post_price').click(function(){
            $('#post_price_false').attr('checked',false);
            $('#post_price_true').attr('checked',true);
          });

          });</script>
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all problem in jquery, i redid script for this:

```
$('#post_price').click(function(){
            $('#post_price_false').attr('checked',false);
            $('#post_price_true').attr('checked',true);
```

to:

```
$('#post_price').click(function(){
                $('#post_price_false').prop('checked',false);
                $('#post_price_true').prop('checked',true);
```